# How to show that if $X_n \downarrow 0$ then $P(X_n >\epsilon) \downarrow 0$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

My solution is as follows:

If $X_n \downarrow 0$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0~ \exists N\ge n $ such that $X_n < \epsilon$. This means that

$$I_{X_n \ge \epsilon} = I_{X_n = \epsilon} + I_{X_n > \epsilon} =0$$

Now if I take expectations, then

$$P(X_n=e) +P(X_n > \epsilon) = 0$$

Since probabilities are non-negative, this means that $P(X_n > \epsilon) = 0$ and the proof is complete.

I can't help but have the feeling it's somehow wrong. First it seems like I proved a much stronger condition and two, if $X_n$ is a continuous function that limits to a singularity, the probability of $X_n$ being greater than a certain number will never be actually 0.

So where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Mike's comments, I am trying the following:

Define $E_n = \cup_{i \ge n}\{X_i > \epsilon\}$, the set of points $\omega \in \Omega$ for which the sequence $X_i(ω)$, for $i \ge n$, is above $\epsilon$ at least once. To show that $P(E_n) \downarrow 0$, I proceed as follows:

$$P(E_n) = P(\omega \in \cup_{i \ge n}\{X_i > \epsilon\})$$

By the definition of pointwise convergence, I can claim that for each $\omega$, $\exists N \ge n  $ such that $X_i(\omega) < \epsilon$. Essentially I can always take an $N$ big enough to knock out any $\omega$ from $E_n$. Then given an $\epsilon$, I take such $N$, which means that for $i > N$,

$$I_{X_i(\omega) > \epsilon} = 0 $$

Taking its expectation, I can say that

$$P(E_n) = 0 $$

From here I'm not sure how to show that $P(E_n)$ is strictly greater than $P(X_n > \epsilon)$.

Comment: Even though you can knock out _any_ $\omega$ from $E_n$, there isn't necessarily a single $N$ which knocks out _every_ $\omega$ from $E_n$, for $n\ge N$. So you can't say that $E_n$ is empty. However, your argument about every $\omega$ being knocked out by some $N$ does let you say that $\bigcap_{n\ge 1}E_n$ is empty. We also have that $E_1\supset E_2\supset\dots$ Try to combine those last two facts to show that $P(E_n)\downarrow 0$ (you won't be able to show $P(E_n)=0$).

Answer (score 0):

You went wrong in your first statement. If $X_n\downarrow0$, it means that $X_n$ converges to zero pointwise, so that *for each* $\omega\in \Omega$, and all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ so that $n>N$ implies $X_n(\omega)<\epsilon$. You can only say what you wrote, $X_n<\epsilon$ for $n>N$, when $X_n\downarrow 0$ uniformly.

If you still want a hint, let $E_n=\bigcup_{i\ge n}\{X_i>\epsilon\}$. In words, $E_n$ is the set of points $\omega\in \Omega$ for which the sequence $X_i(\omega)$, for $i\ge n$, is above $\epsilon$ at least once. Using $X_n\downarrow 0$ pointwise, which shows that $X_n(\omega)<\epsilon$ eventually, show that $P(E_n)\downarrow 0$, and then use that $P(E_n)>P(X_n>\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it halfway done, could you have a look?